# How to generate different random numbers with same function c#

Tags: c#, random, xamarin

In my program, i have the following codes in 2 classes:

```
Random Rand = new Random ();
        _x = (Rand.Next (0, 31));
        _y = (Rand.Next (0, 23));
```

The problem is when the program runs. Both the classes generates the exact same number. How can I code this in a way that both of the coordinates (_x & _y) are generated differently so i can have two different coordinates?

I am using C# in Xamarin Studio.

Comment: reuse the same Random instance.

Comment: Are those two different classes created almost at the same time? Almost simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the two classes are instantianted with different seeds for `Random`.  If the two classes are instantiated close together, the clock may not have moved on to the next tick and they both get the same seed.  You need to ensure that the two classes get different seeds.

One way to do this is to use a master `Random` to generate the seeds for the other two instances:

```
Random masterRandom = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
Random r1 = new Random(masterRandom.Next(0, 100000));
Random r2 = new Random(masterRandom.Next(0, 100000));
```

Because the clock is only called once, there is no problem with two calls close together.  The other instances of `Random` take their seeds from `masterRandom`, not the clock.